# react-hook-form in combination with react-hook-recaptcha on Gatsby: SSR errors when reloading

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-hook-form

I am a bit stuck on how to implement a ReCaptcha to my Gatsby form. I use Sendgrid and Gatsby Functions to send the emails out to my account and this is working. But right now I am trying to get the recaptcha working, but without success. After reload I do get SSR errors and I tried a lot to get this working. The error message is not clear. It is only saying the page cannot be loaded without skipping SSR.

My files:

Form Component:

```js
import * as React from "react"

// Library Imports
import { useState } from "react"

// Components
import { Layout } from "../components/layout"
import useFormWithRecaptcha from "../components/useformWithRecaptcha"

// Icons
import { MailIcon, PhoneIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline"

export default function ContactForm() {
  const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(false)

  const [serverState, setServerState] = React.useState({ formSent: false })

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch(`/api/form`, {
      method: `POST`,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "content-type": `application/json`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(`response from API:`, body)
      })
  }

  const {
    register,
    errors,
    recaptchaLoaded,
    recaptchaComponent,
    executeRecaptcha,
  } = useFormWithRecaptcha({ onSubmit })

  console.log({ errors })

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="px-4 py-8 mx-auto mb-4 max-w-7xl sm:py-14 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="relative ">
          <h2 className="sr-only">Contact us</h2>

            {/* Contact form */}
            <div className="px-6 py-10 sm:px-10 lg:col-span-2 xl:p-12">
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">
                Laat een bericht voor ons achter!
              </h3>
              <form
                onSubmit={executeRecaptcha}
                // action="/api/form"
                // method="POST"
                className="grid grid-cols-1 mt-6 gap-y-6 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-x-8"
              >
                {recaptchaComponent}
                <div>
                  <label
                    htmlFor="firstName"
                    className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                  >
                    Voornaam
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="first-name"
                      id="first-name"
                      w
                      autoComplete="given-name"
                      className="block w-full px-4 py-3 text-gray-900 border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-mainPink-300 focus:border-mainPink-300"
                      required
                      {...register("firstName", {
                        required: true,
                        maxLength: 100,
                      })}
                    />
                    {/* {errors.firstName && (
                      <p className="mt-2 text-sm tracking-widest transition-opacity duration-1000 transform text-mainPink-400">
                        Dit is een verplicht veld
                      </p>
                    )} */}
                  </div>
                </div>

               // ...More form elements

                <div className="sm:col-span-2 sm:flex sm:justify-end">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={!recaptchaLoaded}
                    className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-full px-6 py-3 mt-2 text-base font-medium text-white border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm bg-mainPink-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-mainPink-300 sm:w-auto"
                  >
                    Versturen
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { useRecaptcha } from "react-hook-recaptcha"

const recaptchaContainerId = "recaptcha-container"

const useFormWithRecaptcha = ({ onSubmit, ...formConfig }) => {
  const formMethods = useForm(formConfig)
  const onSubmitRef = useRef(onSubmit)
  const formMethodsRef = useRef(formMethods)

  const windowGlobal = typeof window !== "undefined" && window

  useEffect(() => {
    onSubmitRef.current = onSubmit
    formMethodsRef.current = formMethods
  })

  const successCallback = (response) => {
    return formMethodsRef.current.handleSubmit((data) => {
      //add recaptcha field to data
      return onSubmitRef.current({ ...data, "g-recaptcha-response": response })
    })()
  }

  const { recaptchaLoaded, recaptchaWidget } = useRecaptcha({
    containerId: recaptchaContainerId,
    sitekey: "6Le...",
    size: "invisible",
    successCallback,
  })

  const executeRecaptcha = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (recaptchaWidget !== null) {
      windowGlobal.grecaptcha.reset(recaptchaWidget)
      windowGlobal.grecaptcha.execute(recaptchaWidget)
    }
  }

  const resetRecaptcha = () => {
    if (recaptchaWidget !== null) {
      windowGlobal.grecaptcha.reset(recaptchaWidget)
    }
  }

  const recaptchaComponent = <div id={recaptchaContainerId} />

  return {
    ...formMethods,
    recaptchaLoaded,
    recaptchaComponent,
    executeRecaptcha,
    resetRecaptcha,
  }
}

export default useFormWithRecaptcha
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you mention that the issue appeared with the inclusion of `react-hook-recaptcha`, I'd try bypassing the loading of the dependency during the SSR by (in your `gatsby-node.js`):

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ loaders, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  config.module.rules = [
    {
      test: /react-hook-recaptcha/,
      use: loaders.null(),
    },
  ];
};
```